# A matrix that lies in the U(3) group but neither in O(3) nor in SU(3)?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

How to find a matrix that lies in the U(3) group but neither in O(3) nor in SU(3)?
I would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, consider the matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{i&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1}.
$$

Comment: I tried to verify that this matrix lies in U(3), but as a I further proceeded I wasn't able to verify that this matrix isn't a part of the O(3) group. The prerequisite of A being a part of the group O(3) is that A^T*A=I, and in this case A^T is A^(*) or A^H, so its the same proof for both U(3) and O(3) which means that A is both part of U(3) and O(3). I am not sure whether I made a mistake somewhere. I would be really grateful for further clarification!

Comment: @OceaniaSaraswati The prerequisite for a matrix $A$ to be a part of $O(3)$ is that it **has real entries** and satisfies $A^TA = I$. This matrix does not have real entries.

Comment: Omg how could I forget that thank you so much for helping me out and responding that quickly!! Have a nice day